# Como extraigo de un $.getJSON un dato para luego compararlo usando php sin que aparezca la alerta

Tags: php, javascript

con el siguiente script se obtiene el país del visitante a mi pagina

```
<script> $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',function(data){alert('País: ' + data.address.country); }); </script>
```

como logro extraer el dato dentro de data.address.country para luego usarlo en comparaciones con php sin que aparezca la alerta.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de jQuery usas?

Comment: Estoy usando la 2.1.4

Comment: Hola fernando primero gracias por responderme, hice esto
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',
            function (data) {
                var pais = data.address.country;
            });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "recibodatos.php",
        data: {
            pais: pais
        },
        success: function (responseServer) {
        }
    });
</script>

Pero me marca un error en el cuarto paso en la segunda linea.

Comment: estoy usando la version 5.6 de php, asi que no se si pueda ser eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me imagino que también estás usando `jQuery` lo cual no especificaste. De igual manera, te comento:

Pueden haber múltiples maneras de lograr el objetivo que necesitas.

1. Para no mostrar la alerta, necesitas removerla del script dentro de la `function` que hay dentro de tu código. Justo en la parte siguiente: `alert('País: ' + data.address.country);`  Esta función de javascript manda una alert al navegador y puede lucir así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces y en orden de que esa alerta ya no te salga, tu código javascript debería de quedar de la siguiente manera (oberva cómo removimos la función `alert` del script)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',
        function(data){
            //justo removimos la línea donde teníamos nuestro alert

        });
</script>
```

2. Ahora que ya logramos remover lo que hace alertar a nuestro navegador, vamos a guardar en una variable el valor del país, entonces sería algo así usando el código anterior:

   ```
       $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',
       function(data){
           var pais = data.address.country;
       });
   ```

   Por favor observa cómo hemos guardado en la variable `pais` el valor de "MÉXICO" que nos devuelve la petición que haces.
3. Ahora, para poder enviarlo a un archivo `php` dentro del servidor, existen diferentes maneras. Podrías utilizar `AJAX` porque justo aprovechando que ya estamos con `jQuery` (puedes leer más información sobre esto [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)) se nos hará más fácil. Entonces, creamos la petición (usando el mismo código anterior) y crearemos dentro de tu proyecto raíz un archivo `.php` que lo llamaremos para este ejemplo `recibodatos.php`

Entonces y dejando solo el código necesario agregaríamos esto a nuestro código javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "recibodatos.php",
    data : {
        pais : pais
    },
    success : function(responseServer) {

    }
});
```

Observa cómo nuestro script ajax nos permite especificar en la propiedad `url` la ruta de nuestro archivo `.php` que recibirá todos los datos que enviemos en la propiedad `data` (si observas, se la estamos enviando como un objeto)

4. Para finalizar y una vez creado nuestro archivo `recibodatos.php` que dijimos en el punto número 3, vamos a escribir el siguiente código `php` que nos ayudará a recibir los datos por método POST (también se lo indicamos en la propiedad `type` de nuestra petición `AJAX` en el punto número 3).

recibodatos.php

```
<?php
    $pais_recibido = $_POST["pais"];
    echo "Mi país es: " . $pais_recibido;
?>
```

Por favor observa cómo nos hemos ayudado de la variable `$_POST` que recibe de manera nativa datos a través del método http `POST` (puedes leer más acerca de esto [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php)). Hemos guardado en la variable `$pais_recibido` el valor de lo que obtuvimos desde nuestra petición `AJAX` y que enviamos como `pais` y que si notas, la estamos recibiendo con el mismo nombre como `$_POST["pais"]`. Para este caso, si desde `jQuery` nos enviamos el valor de `México` entonces desde php recibiríamos ese mismo valor de `México` para poder trabajarlo.

Espero que esta parte te haya quedado muy clara, si no, estoy atento a tus comentarios si necesitas más ayuda al respecto.

**Actualización**:

Te muestro el código completo `javascript` porque estás teniendo problemas al enviar el valor de la variable. Veamos:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',
    function(data){
        var pais = data.address.country;
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "recibodatos.php",
            data : {
                pais : pais
            },
            success : function(responseServer) {

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Por favor observa cómo incluí la librería de jquery y después el código que se enviará al servidor con la petición `AJAX`. El detalle que estás poniendo la petición fuera de la función de respuesta de tu primera petición.

Comment: En el cuarto paso me marca un error, lo he hecho de esta manera:
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',
            function (data) {
                var pais = data.address.country;
            });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "recibodatos.php",
        data: {
            pais: pais
        },
        success: function (responseServer) {
        }
    });
</script>
<?php
$pais_recibido = $_POST["pais"];
echo "Mi país es: " . $pais_recibido;
?>

Comment: Todo lo hice en recibodatos.php

Comment: Me podrías decir el error que te dice?

Comment: Aviso : Índice indefinido: pais en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ indenex \ recibodatos.php en la línea 21 Mi país es:

Comment: $pais_recibido = $_POST["pais"]; esta es la linea 21

Comment: Es porque se está perdiendo la variable, te voy a editar la respuesta para que veas cómo debe de ser el código completo.

Comment: Por favor ve la actualización

Comment: Aun sigue el mismo error

Comment: Estoy usando php 5.6.40 y jquery 2.1.4 por si algo.

Comment: Me llama la atención que el error te lo da en la línea 21, ¿qué código tienes antes?

Comment: lo que me dijiste antes de la actualizacion, lo tenia separado, pero sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Comment: <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',
    function(data){
        var pais = data.address.country;
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "recibodatos.php",
            data : {
                pais : pais
            },
            success : function(responseServer) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: <?php
$pais_recibido = $_POST["pais"];
echo "Mi país es: " . $pais_recibido;
?>

Comment: asi lo tengo ahora, pero el error persiste.

Comment: Es posible que puedas enviarme el proyecto que has hecho a este correo erikmarbad@gmail.com porque si a ti te esta funcionando es posible que el error se deba a que las versiones de php o jquery no son compatibles con el script con el que me estas ayudando, independientemente si me lo envias o no, puedes indicarme que versiones estas usando?

Comment: seguro, te lo mando

Comment: gracias por enviarlo, lo probe pero aun sigue el error... crees que la version de php tenga algo que ver (uso la 5.6.40)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102988/discussion-between-fernando-urban-and-erik).